# The cached table is not cached but in memory when using hsqldb

Tags: hsqldb, caching

I am trying the cached table feature of hsqldb version 2.2.5 .

Just using JDBC batch insert into one table, the odd thing is if
 I run the my test alone, although I used the ***create cached table***, 
but it is still using the memory mode, because after ***100,0000 records***, **OOM**.

But if I run some other test before this test case or use `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:HSQLDB;hsqldb.default_table_type=cached`
, it will use cached table.

*Anyway, I don't want to use cached for default.*

The cached table performance looks like this 
***after 2600000 records, the performance decreased a lot.*** 
***after 3600000 records, it becomes very slow***

**Perhaps some indexes occupies the memory fully makes the JVM becomes slow.
Not because of db itself**

Two sub questions

*1)Any other config to force the cached table is using cached mode?*

*2)Any db config will help to increase the performace of cached table?*

(With JDK1.6 -Xmx1024m)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URL that you report is for a `mem:` (everything in memory - no persistence) database. In this setup, any reference or setting for CACHED tables is simply ignored and the data is stored in memory.

The CACHED table feature is available is `file:` (persist to disk) databases. These databases also support persistent MEMORY tables (all data is stored in memory). The data for both CACHED and MEMORY tables is stored on disk in `file:` databases.

Regarding performnce of CACHED, recently used rows are cached in memory and changes are saved to disk when the cache gets full.

The database engine uses `java.nio` methods to access databases that are above 16MB on disk, and below a certain limit. To improve performance, you can increase the limit with the `hsqldb.nio_max_size` property or the equivalent SQL statement.

In general, disks are slow in random access mode (maximum 100 access per second). Use of cache, nio, and other strategies can reduce effective access time, but only to some extent.

Also note you can turn data logging off during bulk inserts, and turn it on again for normal database operations.

These issues and settings are covered in this chapter of the Guide.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html

Comment: @fredit, thanks for the helpful advice.But I felt very strange, I do  see difference without using CACHED even using mem in URL. Comparing total records from 3600000 to 1000000. I felt strange if it's not due to using CACHED table. +1

Comment: @fredit, I really hope if we can use cached table in mem url. Due to I want to mix the memory table and cached table in using hsqldb. It's possible right?

Comment: @Clark, yes you can mix. Updated the answer. Please read the Guide for details.

Comment: @fredit,why I don't want to use file mode is due to I want  the DB to be cleanup when I shutdown JVM and reconnect to it. Can I set something to let it work like this.

Comment: You must use the file: mode to persist data. You can clear the db objects with SQL statements.

Comment: Perhaps I can clean up those files before I connect to it.